# How can I find the local docker ip address of a registry service?

Tags: docker, ip, registry

I have created a local docker registry and I want to access it from inside another container/service `test`. The compose file looks like:

```
version: "3.4"

services:

  registry:
    image: "registry"
    container_name: registry
    restart: always
    environment:
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: "true"
    ports:
      - ${REGISTRY_PORT:-5100}:5000
    volumes:
      - ${REGISTRY_PATH:-./registry}:/var/lib/registry:rw

  test:
    profiles: ["test"]
    image: "python:3.11-slim-bookworm"
    container_name: test
    depends_on:
     - registry
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

which is built by

```
$ docker compose -f docker-compose.yml run --build -d --name test test

CONTAINER ID   NAMES            IMAGE                       STATUS
202d6d5b1a81   test             python:3.11-slim-bookworm   Up About a minute
24f1773fd047   registry         registry                    Up About a minute
```

after which I can run the following commands from **inside** the `test` container

```
$ docker exec -it test bash

$ curl -v registry

*   Trying 172.21.0.2:80...
* connect to 172.21.0.2 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to registry port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to registry port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

$ curl registry:5100/v2/_catalog

curl: (7) Failed to connect to registry port 5100 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

$ curl 172.21.0.1:5100/v2/_catalog

{"repositories":[]}
```

The networks I have are

```
docker network inspect $(docker network ls | awk '$3 == "bridge" { print $1}') | jq -r '.[] | .Name + " " + .IPAM.Config[0].Subnet' -

bridge 172.17.0.0/16
foo_default 172.21.0.0/16
```

I don't understand why I can't access the local registry from its ip 172.19.3 **.2**, but only the ip 172.19.3 **.1**.

Comment: Ccheck ip a,nad show output for docker registry.

Comment: Inside the `update` container, make a normal DNS lookup for the other container's Compose service name `registry`.  You shouldn't need to directly know its Docker-internal IP address (unless you're writing the network layer by hand).

Comment: @DavidMaze Hmm, with the `host/dig registry` command I get that regisitry is attached to 172.19.3**.2** while curl just answers to registry 172.19.3**.1**

Comment: Are you actually trying to connect to the service from the `update` container?  Or, if it's a Docker registry container and you're mounting the host's Docker socket, are you trying to use this as the registry location when dynamically creating another container?

Comment: @DavidMaze From inside the update container I can connect to the registry via the **.1** ip, not the **.2** that when I run `host registry`.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show the code that makes the connection?  As @AlirezaPourchali's [answer](/a/77166781) indicates, you shouldn't need these IP addresses at all.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, I have edited to show exactly the steps I do with a minimal docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 1):

You are exposing your registry through port `5100` from you localhost(your computer) , the `172.19.3.1` ip address is for your own pc and the port 5100 is exposed as well , by default docker exposes ports on all interfaces. so you connect to the container through your host machine.

If you want to bypass the host and connect to the container from other container , it is suggested to use your **service name** which resolves to the ip address of the other container.

In your docker-compose, your registry service name is `registry` and the your service2 service name is `test` , in the service2 container if you run `nslookup registry` or `curl -v registry` you will see that the name gets resolved to an ip address.

so if you run

```
curl registry:5000/v2/_catalog
```

you should get the same response
just pay attention to your ports! you exposed 5100 via host but the container is exposing port 5000.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Thank, but the `registry` container resolves to 172.19.3. **.2** while in the service2 container I can only connect to the registry service through the **.1** address (not **.2** which is what the registry resolves to). So `curl registry:5000/v2/_catalog` returns ` Failed to connect to registry port 5100` (while using ip **.1** works).

Comment: pay attention to your ports! the port `5100` is exposed via host  but the container port is `5000`. in your updated question you have to run `curl registry:5000/v2/_catalog` not `curl registry:5100/v2/_catalog`